# Ubuntu 20.04.3 does not boot after kernel upgrade

Tags: boot, kernel

I have the following kernels in "Advanced options for Ubuntu" menu in boot page:

- Ubuntu, with Linux 5.13.0-41-generic
- Ubuntu, with Linux 5.13.0-41-generic (recovery mode)
- Ubuntu, with Linux 5.13.0-40-generic
- Ubuntu, with Linux 5.13.0-40-generic (recovery mode)

I can only boot with 5.13.0-40. How can I find the reason why 41 does not boot? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't boot"? There may be a few reasons: installation of the latest kernel was interrupted, you installed some graphics drivers without DKMS, etc.

Comment: I only see a black screen with the text "loading initial ramdisk...". Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Boot with a previous kernel and run `sudo apt install -f && sudo apt upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

First try boot using previous kernel and run software update once more time.
Remove all eternal devices or update drivers:

```
sudo apt install dkms; sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

If all above will not help, choose stable kernel with help of grub-customizer. Most issues resolving in time after next kernel release.

Comment: I did this, and while it booted fine, it changed my GPU driver to point to the proprietary one (Nvidia) instead of the open-source one I was using (Nouveau). This ideally would be fine, but the problem is I use 3 displays, 2 of which are widescreen, and the Nvidia driver limits the width of 1 of the widescreen displays to 1920 instead of 2560.